# PPTPD VPN Connects but no Internet access

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have set up a VPN server on CentOS and followed the guide from here:

[Guide To PPTPD](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp)

I did everything except the firewall because if i keep iptables on, it won't let me connect to the VPN connection, so instead of taking the headache, I turned off firewall using

```
service iptables stop
```

Now it lets me connect but it wont let me access the internet resources, however I can use the VPN server resources fine. If you have any questions feel free to ask, Also here's the test username and password if you would like to see

```
Server: 198.20.66.236
Username: stackoverflow
Password: testpass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your vpn details but seems like you're using wrong remote ips. the remote ips should be within from your server not just any range. you're you are using remote ips  starting from 192.168  which is a local ip range, rather use a range which is in your case 198.20.66.237-240 or w/e the ending range is.

Answer (score 0):

Of course these addresses can only be used if they are not already owned by some other server.